# Scons Compile Error when switching from OSX 10.6 to 10.7

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, scons

I am migrating from a Snow Leopard (10.6.8) MAC to a Lion MAC (10.7.5).  I haven't changed anything in the code or the build scripts, but once I try to build my project using SCONS on OSX Lion, I get the following errors:

```
gcc -arch i386 -o build/osx/objs/installer/Controller.o -c -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -x objective-c++ -Oz -m32 -Wall -fno-common -fvisibility=hidden -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -fno-common -fvisibility=hidden -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5 -g -DOS_OSX=1 -D_OS_NAME=osx -D_PRODUCT_VERSION=1.1.0 -D_PRODUCT_NAME=Aspen -D_GLOBAL_NS_VARNAME=Aspen -D_CONFIG_FILENAME=Aspen.config -D_BOOT_RUNTIME_FLAG= -D_BOOT_HOME_FLAG= -D_DISTRIBUTION_URL=smithmicro.com -D_CRASH_REPORT_URL=smithmicro.com/p/v1/app-crash-report -DOS_32=1 -DDEBUG=1 -I. -Ikroll -Ibuild/osx/sdk/include -Ikroll/libkroll -Ikroll/libkroll/utils installer/osx/Controller.mm
In file included from kroll/libkroll/utils/../base.h:10,
                 from kroll/libkroll/utils/utils.h:8,
                 from installer/osx/Controller.h:8,
                 from installer/osx/Controller.mm:6:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/string:44:28: error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
```

I have the 10.5 sdk here: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk.  When I compare the 10.5 SDK on my Snow Leopard to Lion MAC, they look they the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT

After turning on verbose information I can see this on the 10.7 machine for include paths:

```
 /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include
 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward
 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include
 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

When I look at the 10.6 machine it has

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin10
```

That is the missing include, but I'm not sure how that gets included on 10.6 and not 10.7, its not explicitly added anywhere in the build scripts.  I believe its based off the BaseSDK of the build, and they are the same.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the include paths. Even though you didnt change your source code, its not uncommon for the lib/include paths to be slightly different when changing OS versions. Im not familiar with libkroll, but maybe it needs to be ported to Mac Lion.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I added more to the question, I found the missing include path, but I'm not sure why its not added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up creating my own alias folder called

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin11
```

on my 10.7 machine and now everything compiles. I wonder why the Xcode/SDK installation didn't create this folder for me, like it does on 10.6

Comment: Also works (apparently) on 10.8. I would have expect a symlink with *-darwin12 but version 11 is still used (apparently).